# How to find 3D points coordinates in a perpendicular plane to a given vector

Tags: math, vector, geometry, computational-geometry, vector-graphics

I have two points in a 3d space, one point is (x,0,z) and the other one is the origin (0,0,0), through those points there is a passing line with length L that is starting from the first point and continuing after the origin point, in the end of this line there is a perpendicular (to the line) flat board with dimensions of W x H, the line ends in the middle of this board.

Assume that x,z,L,H,W are given, I need a way to find all the 3D points coordinates where those points forming a pixels image over the board (meaning each point has a distance of 1 from its left, right, top, bottom neighboring points).

Attached a pretty ugly drawing :) I made trying to illustrate the problem (I marked the pixels points with two question marks but I need them all).

Thanks.

[image: ugly_drawing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to define that plane. But there is no selected direction to build a grid uniquelly.

Let we choose OY direction as base (because normal has zero Y-component).

So we have:

Normal vector `N = (xx, 0, zz)`  //I renamed values to avoid confusion with coordinate 
variables

Unit normal vector `n = (nx, 0, nz)`, where

```
 nx = xx / Sqrt(xx*xx+zz*zz)
 nz = zz / Sqrt(xx*xx+zz*zz)
```

Base point

```
B = (bx, 0, bz) =  (xx - nx * L, 0, zz - nz * L)
```

Unit base vector in the plane

```
dy = (0, 1, 0)
```

Another base vector

```
dc = dy x n  //vector product
   = (-bz, 0, bx)
```

Now it is possible to generate a grid, using integer indexes `i, j` in ranges `(-W/2..W/2)` and `(-H/2.. H/2)`. Grid nodes coordinates:

```
  x(i, j) = bx - j * bz
  y(i, j) = 0 + i 
  z(i, j) = bz + j * bx
```

Comment: Many many thanks!

I was missing the unit base vector dy = (0,1,0)
But I'm still not sure why this vector supposed to be on the board plane, can you please explain why or give some intuition?
Thank you.

Comment: It is perpendicular to normal (hence lies in the plane) because dot product of this vector and normal is zero `nx * 0 +  0 * 1 +  nz * 0 = 0`. `dy = (0,1,0)` is not unique base direction - but it is simple and natural in our case.